# Access every variable individually in quick.db?

Tags: discord, discord.js, quick.db

I code a discord bot in discord.js and I have an economy with hunger and fun as a variable. I want those variables to decrease over time, and I would need a for loop to do this, but I don't know how I would access every single account hunger variable. Normally what I would do to change something is have the user be the message author id but since it happens at all times i cant connect it to a authors message.

Comment: Hi!, uhh dude... We seriously not understand what you asking. plus you didn't even try and tell some of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.